# Role and capacitance of small capacitor near USB 3 socket of HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 (mainboard model YOP)?

Tags: capacitor, motherboard

During rework for replacement of the USB 3 socket on an HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3, **I lost the small orange circled capacitor**. I looked everywhere and cannot find it.
The motherboard model is YOP (or Y0P ?).

[image: Capacitor near USB 3 socket on HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3]

So far, **I cannot figure out the role of this capacitor for the EliteBook x360 1030 G3**.

[image: Missing lost capacitor on USB 3 socket of HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3]

The track from this capacitor leads to the yellow circled pad, which belongs to a set of 3 soldering pads.

From the location of these pads, I assume it could be a location reserved for a diode informing about data transfer through the USB (on other laptop models), but this is just an hypothesis.

In this context **can I simply ignore this capacitor and safely use the USB 3 socket without it?**
Or does it possibly relies a track for the grounding of the USB socket? Or other role?

Secondly, if I replace this capacitor, **how can I know or guess its capacitance**?

Lastly, **can this capacitor easily be found with the correct capacitance on another laptop motherboard or USB flash drive?** I have many defective ones that could serve as donor.

[image: Location of unsoldered USB 3 socket on HP EliteBook 1030 G3]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the pad you circled in yellow isn't the only place that capacitor is attached to; there's also a via going off to who-knows-where right next to the missing capacitor. Since this is a motherboard (which typically means 12+ layers), the via probably goes to an internal layer and there's no hope of tracing it further without just buzzing it out with a continuity probe.

Comment: That yellow-circled footprint is a little confusing, actually. At first glance it looks like a MOSFET, with a thin gate trace, source connected to the ground plane, and a thick drain trace. Except none of the traces are connected to the right pins for that, if it's the usual pinout. Most FETs in that type of three-pin package have the gate on the lower left pin, the source on the lower right, and drain on the top. This looks like the gate is on the lower right, drain on the lower left, and source on top, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Since one side of the capacitor is connected to what appears to be ground, it is very likely it was used for either decoupling or snubbing of a usb power pin. If this is the case, it is almost certainly fine without it.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. On the 2nd picture, the uppermost pad is connected to a large copper area which I assume is the ground. The track coming from the yellow circled pad is likely the negative, because it is connected to a both a pin, but also to the capacitor, which likely acts as a voltage stabilizer, and is is connected to GND, like the afore mentioned pin. The rightmost of the thee pads would be the positive that it is connected to nothing, the track being interrupted by some "missing" component. I have a picture from before the repair confirming that there was no component at this location.